# public function get_word() : string

Tags: php

Что означает конструкция вида

```
public function get_word() : string
{
    return 'Test';
}
```

Что означает : string? тип входных данных?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration  и   https://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration

Answer (score 1):

> Что означает : string? тип входных данных?

Это означает тип возвращаемого значения. То есть функция `get_word()` должна вернуть строку. Что собственно она и делает.

Хорошо описано здесь https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-type-hinting.html